# Entity framework 6 projection generates SQL equivalent to "Select *" and does not produce WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I'm maintaining an ASP.NET WebAPI2 application with Entity framework 6 and MSSQL server database. The IoC container is Castle Windsor. I have a method on my repository that I use to get some details for a user from DB. Since I don't need every column, I thought I'd use projection. The problem is that the generated SQL selects ALL the columns in my table.
Here's the DbContext

```
public partial class SecurityContext : DbContext
{
    public SecurityContext()
        : base("name=SecurityContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> secUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Here's where the context is declared/initialized in the repository

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbContext context;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        context = new SecurityContext();
    }

    public BaseRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    } 
    //elided
}
```

and here's the method in the repository

```
public User FindUserForLoginVerification(string name)
{         
    var loginInfo = context.Set<User>()
        .Where(c => c.LoginName == name)
        .Select(c => new 
        { 
            LoginName = c.LoginName, 
            Password = c.HashedPassword, 
            Salt = c.PasswordHashSalt 
        })
        .SingleOrDefault();

    return new User() { 
        LoginName = loginInfo.LoginName, 
        HashedPassword = loginInfo.Password, 
        PasswordHashSalt = loginInfo.Salt                
    };
}
```

Here's the output SQL.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent1].[CreatedByUserId] AS [CreatedByUserId], 
[Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
[Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
[Extent1].[DefaultCulture] AS [DefaultCulture], 
[Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
[Extent1].[IsExcludedFromPasswordPolicy] AS [IsExcludedFromPasswordPolicy], 
[Extent1].[IsChangePassword] AS [IsChangePassword], 
[Extent1].[IsLocked] AS [IsLocked], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[LastPasswordChangeDate] AS [LastPasswordChangeDate], 
[Extent1].[LoginName] AS [LoginName], 
[Extent1].[NumberOfFailedLoginAttempts] AS [NumberOfFailedLoginAttempts], 
[Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
[Extent1].[PasswordHashSalt] AS [PasswordHashSalt]
[Extent1].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. Any ideas will be appreciated.

EDIT: I just noticed something strange - in the generated SQL there's no WHERE clause, which means that all the rows are selected from the database, brought to the client, and filtered there.
EDIT 2: the same SQL is produced by using the LINQ query syntax.
EDIT 3: After writing a unit test where I instantiate the repository and service manually (instead of leaving it to CastleWindsor), the SQL produced when running the test has the WHERE clause.

Comment: In your context, how are the sets declared? Do they have `public virtual` or just `public`

Comment: Why `context.Set<User>()` and not `context.secUsers()` ?

Comment: @GregoryHouseMD because in the repository, the context is passed as DbContext. I've tried casting it to SecurityContext before answering your comment, but it did not produce any difference.

Comment: Have you tried  `var loginInfo = context.Set<User>()
        .Where(c => c.LoginName == name).ToList().Select`...?

Comment: @hmnzr Yes, the resulting SQL is still the same.

Comment: can you create an empty console application, create a new dbcontext and try exactly this query? i have just did that and i cannot get the behavior that you have

Comment: Switching to `FirstOrDefault` might change something...but still, the `WHERE` clause is nowhere to be dounf

Comment: I wrote an unit test to avoid using Castle Windsor (I thought it is the culprit), and got slightly different SQL - now I have the WHERE clause. I've tried FirstOrDefault() as well, but no luck.

Comment: What SQL is generated with`.SingleOrDefault(c => c.LoginName == name)`?

Comment: Something else; if you add `.AsQueryable<>` after 'Set<User>()`, does that change anything?

Comment: @Loetn It produces the same SQL as when I use Where().

Comment: Check where `.Where(` is coming from - if it's coming from [`Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx) rather than [`Queryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable(v=vs.100).aspx), that's what you'll see/expect.

Comment: I've seen cases where its the anonymous type that causes this.  Can you try creating a dummy class and projecting onto that?  It might make a difference for some bizarre reason.

Comment: @Loetn I added .AsQueryable<User>(), but nothing changed. The Select() method works on IQueryable<T>, and the DbSet also implements IQueryable, so that shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: @Amy I added a dummy class with the necessary properties, but the resulting SQL is still the same.

Comment: @user2936023 Is this the only query that produces this behavior in your application? `Context` is of type `DbContext`, right (because your `Set<T>` is executed on the database)?

Comment: yes, the instance called "context" is passed as DbContext (I guess because the repository extends a generic repository). I've tested it and I get the same behavior on all the operations performed via this context - the produced SQL is functionally equivalent to "SELECT * from TableName".

Comment: Can you show us how the `context` variable is declared / initialized?

Comment: What do you get if you "print" (or inspect, trace, whatever) the run-time type of `context.Set<User>()`? I'd expect `DbSet<User>` but I wonder if your context implementation is providing something different.

Comment: Most repository patterns return an `IEnumerable<T>` which will prevent further manipulation of the SQL by LINQ.  So the `.Where` and `.Select` are actually being done on `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an `IQueryable<T>`, so your attempts at using projection to reduce the number of columns being fetched won't work.

Comment: @RobertMcKee you are right, but here I'm querying against a DbSet<User>, which implements IQueryable<T>, and the Select method I'm using works on IQueryable. Still, you comment and Garry McGill's answers make a lot of sense, and I'll try to make sure I'm not accidentaly working with IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: I have noticed the same behavior with generic repositories. For example if you had code like this `context.Set<T>().Where(condition).Select(user => user.Name)`, this wouldn't generate a where clause or a projection.

Answer (score 2):

If your `context` is something that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (and not `IQueryable<T>`) from the `Set<T>` method, then that's your problem, because the expression:

```
context.Set<User>
.Where(...)
.Select(...)
.SingleOrDefault()
```

...will read the whole table into memory, and *then* apply the `Where` clause and the projection (`Select`). So, you *would* expect `SELECT * FROM table` behaviour.

The `DbContext` class implementation of `Set<T>` returns a `DbSet<T>` which does implement `IQueryable<T>`, so that would be OK. But since it looks like you have a custom repository implementation, I'm suspicious about what else might be going on behind the scenes...